# How to cache razor pages with their data in Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: caching, blazor, blazor-webassembly

In a Blazor WebAssembly app I want to open a page apply search criteria i.e get all us customers and start editing a customer changing its fields.
Then I want to go to another screen to see something and return to the previous screen to continue my changes to the specific customer without re-entering the previous changes.

I suppose the only way to do this is by caching the pages. But I wonder which of the caching techniques that exist in Blazor Web assembly can cover my needs.

Also notice that this caching would apply to most of the screens of my Blazor app.

Thank you

Comment: You could make it a PWA and make use of the service workers caching. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/progressive-web-app?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#cache-first-fetch-strategy

Comment: How persistent do you want the data?  Just for the SPA session or ..?  Do you leave the page to look up some specific data?  Neil W's answer shows you how you can solve that.  Or is it AdHoc viewing?  It's important to understand that you can't cache components [pages].  You don't control their lifecycle.  What you persist (and reload) is the relevant data from the page.  There are some fairly heavy duty solutions such as Fluxor, or more simple home baked ones.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I would use Neil W's approach

Comment: @BrianParker I will have a look at PWA. Looks interesting. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom caching service for this purpose, but I would not recommend it.

What happens if user doesn't return to complete input.  Then, sometime later decides to input / edit a customer and is presented with information cached from earlier that has nothing to do with the current customer being edited.  Yes, you could make the cache use finer granularity (e.g. include the customer id also) but, again, the whole thing starts to get a bit ugly.

I'm gonna guess that:

> Then I want to go to another screen to see something and return to the
> previous screen to continue my changes

means that the user might need to look up some info relevant to the current editing process to help make a decision on what value should be entered when editing the customer.

If this is the case, I would suggest that you use a sub-component rather than route to another page.

For example:

Your customer editing page will have fields to edit the customer.  You'd have links on that page to allow user to view more detailed information that is relevant.  You could then pop that up in a modal (without leaving the customer editing page) so the user can view what they need to and then close the modal and continue editing without ever having left the customer editing page, so all values will remain.

Doesn't have to be modal.  The sub-component could be embedded in the customer edit page and hidden/shown as and when required.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I guess I would use modal forms in order to provide user of app with extra info that is needed and would avoid routing.

Comment: Yup, I'd go for the modal.  Additionally, you can send event back from the modal to the customer edit page to automatically populate the customer edit model based on items clicked on the modal.  That may be useful for your scenario, instead of user seeing a value on modal and then keying that in to edit screen.